# Finding a way to learn GTK+ 3.x

Tags: c, windows, gtk

Recently I completed my text book "C Primer Plus" and now I want to begin learning how to program GUI applications. After a little search I found that GTK+ is what is said to be a very good widget toolkit to begin with. Unfortunately I can’t find a good way to start learning it. I searched everywhere but all that I find are documentations and tutorials that from my point of view aren’t really for noobs like me. Nowhere is it explained how to even properly download and install it for windows at least (and if possible integrate it in code::blocks as it is my preferred IDE).

So could someone please tell me where I can find some tutorial like this or better a good book??

Comment: There are Windows install instructions on http://www.gtk.org/download/

Comment: What resources did you find? Can you list them and say why they were useless?

Comment: @ptomato yes, after a long search I really found the instructions but do you possibly know how to integrate this in code::blocks. As for the resources they are mainly the documentation and the tutorials provided in the site. The reason they were useless is pretty simple: I somehow can't comprehend them correctly

Comment: What don't you comprehend?